# Wrong content_type_id when using Inheritance with django-taggit

Tags: django-taggit

I defined:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Parent(models.Model):
  tags = TaggableManager()
class Child (models.Model):
   more_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

When I add a Child element using the admin panel (and using Inline I get the "TAGS" field that should be added to the related Parent element) then the content_type_id in in taggit_taggeditem is wrong and points to Child instead of Parent...